# Can I Reverse/upside-down mount SMD LED

Tags: led, surface-mount

I've seen reverse-mount LEDs which are meant to have the light shine through a hole in the PCB, instead of straight off. Is it possible to just add a drill hole for normal LEDs and just place them upside down before soldering?

Is it possible the lense/substrate will melt if reflowed on a hotplate? If it matters any, I've got 0805 components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the package, this can be done.

For my work, we evaluated several types of LEDs, and being mountable "through-PCB" was mandatory.

The right LED shown in the picture can be mounted normal and through-PCB, the second is exclusively for through-PCB, and the LED in the middle is a standard and very common 0603 package, not foreseen for through-PCB mounting.

[image]

It turned out the type in the middle had the best electrical/optical characteristics, and its small size was a benefit for us, too.

The package is a piece of ceramics with metal contacts of almost the same size on top and bottom side. As there are re-reeling companies out there which will turn the LEDs in the reels upside-down, it was possible to machine-place it like any other component:

[image]

Just note that size and tolerance of that transparent resin is not that accurate, so add some extra tolerance for the hole.

About possible temperature issues: During soldering, probably the entire tiny 0603 package will heat up to the solder temperature, so the resin and the LED chip should resist solder temperatures for a short time. Due to the size, I doubt that the resin will cool down faster when mounted normally. But I would recommend to solder at the lowest possible temperature and as short as possible. Also, have a look at soldering recommendations in the data sheet.

In general, no guarantee can be given, but it worked for us quite well.

Comment: Approximately, what was the size of your drill hole

Comment: Actually, it's a milling, long enough that the resin doesn't touch the curvature. The resin was 1.0+/-0.1mm, I think we took 1.2 or 1.3mm width. Just check the datasheet of your LED!

Answer (score 0):

You can make through hole and is ok
Normally they are a little bigger than 0805
I don't see issues